# cgo gets error when called function returns C struct

Tags: windows, dll, cgo

Here is my code. My code is running in Goland on windows 10.
I want to call a function, which is provided by dll file, using cgo.

If that function returns simple type (like int) variables, it works.
But if it returns C struct type (like IMU_STATE in following), an error occurs.

Following is my code:

JoyShockLibrary.h

```cpp
...
typedef struct IMU_STATE
{
    float accelX;
    float accelY;
    float accelZ;
    float gyroX;
    float gyroY;
    float gyroZ;
} IMU_STATE;

JOY_SHOCK_API IMU_STATE JslGetIMUState(int deviceId);
...
```

main.go

```cpp
/*
    #cgo LDFLAGS: -lstdc++ -L. -lJoyShockLibrary

    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>
    #include "JoyShockLibrary.h"
*/
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    dll := syscall.NewLazyDLL("D:\\JoyShockLibrary.dll")

    C_JslGetIMUState := dll.NewProc("JslGetIMUState")
    ret_0, _, _ := C_JslGetIMUState.Call()                    // Error occured here.
}
```

Following is error message:

```
Exception 0xc0000005 0x1 0x0 0x7ff83e6dcebb
PC=0x7ff83e6dcebb
signal arrived during external code execution

runtime.cgocall(0x7ff74dea00a0, 0x7ff74df92620)
        D:/work/code/goroot/go1.20.4/src/runtime/cgocall.go:157 +0x4a fp=0xc0001
15e00 sp=0xc000115dc8 pc=0x7ff74de43caa
syscall.SyscallN(0x7ff83e6dce10?, {0x0?, 0x0?, 0x7ff74dea7c80?})
        D:/work/code/goroot/go1.20.4/src/runtime/syscall_windows.go:557 +0x109 f
p=0xc000115e78 sp=0xc000115e00 pc=0x7ff74de9b3e9
syscall.(*Proc).Call(0xc00007a510?, {0x0?, 0x7ff74deffd40?, 0x7ff74decf201?})   
        D:/work/code/goroot/go1.20.4/src/syscall/dll_windows.go:190 +0x25 fp=0xc
000115eb8 sp=0xc000115e78 pc=0x7ff74dea7885
syscall.(*LazyProc).Call(0xc00007a510, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0})
        D:/work/code/goroot/go1.20.4/src/syscall/dll_windows.go:310 +0x50 fp=0xc
000115ee8 sp=0xc000115eb8 pc=0x7ff74dea7d30
main.main()
        D:/work/code/go/joy-mage/joy_mage/main.go:58 +0xc5 fp=0xc000115f80 sp=0x
c000115ee8 pc=0x7ff74decf365
runtime.main()
        D:/work/code/goroot/go1.20.4/src/runtime/proc.go:250 +0x1f7 fp=0xc000115
fe0 sp=0xc000115f80 pc=0x7ff74de76337
runtime.goexit()
        D:/work/code/goroot/go1.20.4/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1598 +0x1 fp=0xc000
115fe8 sp=0xc000115fe0 pc=0x7ff74de9e7a1
```

Could someone tell me the reason, or how to find reasons? Thanks a lot!